# What does workbench service stand for in NebulaGraph on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nebula-graph

I was checking questions(to hopefully potentially answer them) from this:

[How can I install NebulaGraph databse on AWS without deploying the workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781048/how-can-i-install-nebulagraph-databse-on-aws-without-deploying-the-workbench) but to me, it's even not clear on the question itself.

Could anyone help explain what exactly this **workbench service** is?

Thanks!

BR//Wey

I googled it, walked through the quick guide of NebulaGraph on AWS yet searched the documentations, still no luck to figure out this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for noticing my question, Wey. NebulaGraph workbench is a Linux host, where NebulaGraph ecosystem tools such as Explorer, Dashboard, Analytics, and Exchange are deployed together.

Look at the middle area of the following architecture diagram.
[image: NebulaGraph architecture on AWS]

I guess this is a new feature and I just found out they are updating the docs.

Comment: Wow, Thanks Mr./Ms. @Randomv ! would you mind guide me the URL of this digram in the docs, please?

Comment: Sure. I found this is the GitHub repo of NebulaGraph docs. The URL is https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-docs/blob/v3.1.0/docs-2.0/nebula-cloud/nebula-cloud-on-aws/2.aws-architecture.md

Comment: Looks like the Action to render this MD file is still running 

Comment: The Action succeeded. Now it is on https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.1.0/nebula-cloud/nebula-cloud-on-aws/2.aws-architecture/.